# How to transform Future<List<Map> to List<Map> in Dart language?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a question in coding with dart language. How to transform a Future to the normal List? In my program, I need the result from web to continue next step and I don't know how to do it.
In my case, I need to return the value of variable "data" as a List.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    static List getList() {
    var url = "http://watcherman.cn/web/json.php";
    var data;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
        String jsonContent = contents.toString();
        data = JSON.decode(jsonContent);
      });
    });
    return data;
  }
}
```

But it seems like not execute the network part.
The flutter code part seems can't accept a Future.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static List content = getList();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            itemCount: content.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  child: new Text(content[index]["title"])
              );
            }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should rewrite your `getList` method to return a [`Future<List>`](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures). It's possible to do this with a chain of [`then()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-async/Future/then.html) invocations, but far more readable IMO to use [`async`/`await`](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async).

Once you have a method that returns a `Future<List>`, you can use [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to build a tree that depend on the results of the asynchronous computation.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  static Future<List> getList() async {
    var url = "http://watcherman.cn/web/json.php";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    return response.transform(UTF8.decoder).transform(JSON.decoder).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Futures Demo'),
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getList(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return new Container();
          List content = snapshot.data[0];
          return new ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            itemCount: content.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                child: new Text('${content[index]['title']}'),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes,this is the correct solution. How do I show a refresh indicator while network request happens ?

Comment: Building a Chinese news app?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot escape from being asynchronous.

In Dart, a function either returns a value or a `Future`. It returns a future when the result isn't ready yet when the function returns, it will only be available at a later time.

That means that you are stuck if all you have is a `Future` and you want the value right now, because the value just isn't there yet. You cannot return the `List` *now*, because the `Future<List>` doesn't have a list now, it only has it later.

So, you have to wait for that future, `var data = await client.getUrl(...)...`, and that means that your function must be asynchronous too.
So, make the `getList` function return a `Future<List>` instead of a `List`, because that's all it can do.

The alternative, which Dart doesn't support, would be a blocking operation that stops execution until a value is available, and then continues the normal execution. That's a problem in a single-threaded language (like Dart and JavaScript, which Dart must compile to) because blocking means nothing happens and the UI becoming unresponsive.

So, if your result depends on the value of a future, then your function must be asynchronous too and return its own result as a future.

Comment: Thanks! I have realised this part when I was programing, but had no idea to solve it. The best answer solve this perfectly. The reason I can't achieve my goal is the defect of knowledge of Flutter. But thank you anyway!